# List open ports on linux server

Tags: linux

I have a requirement to list all TCP open ports and also to find server's destination address.Please provide commands.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify on, finding server's destination address part.

Comment: If this is your homework if would have been nice if you'd attempted it yourself first.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `netstat -tnlp` to list all open TCP ports. `netstat -tunlp` to list both TCP & UDP ports.